# Programmatically call navigation controller back button on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uinavigationcontroller

In a UINavigationController-based iPhone app, in a method I would like to perform the programmatic equivalent of the back button being pressed and going back a view.

i.e. automatically press the Jobs button as seen here:

[image: Navigation Controller image]

Is there a generic iOS call I can make, or is more information required?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`UINavigationController`'s [`-popViewControllerAnimated:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc) method should do what you want:

```
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: awesome, thanks to Steve and Niels. The solution I used was   [self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

easy ;)

Comment: this works great except viewcontrollers added on uitabbar. any clues??

Comment: I added `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` but it does nothing, however there is an alert on taping that button which is working.

Comment: Hmm, I get a blank screen, an unresponsive app and the following in the console: "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you don't actually want to PRESS the button programmatically, but simply copy the outcome of pressing the button, you should tell the navigation controller to pop the current view controller.

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

This will remove it from the stack, and return you to the previous view controller.

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3.0**

> Back to the root view

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

> Back to the previous view

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**Swift 2.3**

> Back to the root view

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

> Back to the previous view

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should call

`popViewControllerAnimated:`

which is the opposite of adding view controllers with `pushViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 6):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimates:YES];
```

is the best option but if you are nor on the same view controller class or your delegate changes before your back button method called then you can also try--

first you have to define back button---

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"anyTitleForBackButton" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: @selector(backButtonTapped)];

[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

[newBackButton release];
```

and then in backButtonTapped method you can call--

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desiredViewController animated:YES];
```